# JSON-LD script is showing on Google Structured Data Testing tool and page source but not in Mobile Friendly Test

Tags: seo, google, structured-data, json-ld, mobile-first-index

We have an Angular Universal application which has dynamically loading JSON-LD script tags. These script tags are showing in the page source.

We've tested the same using the Structured Data Testing tool and there are no errors.

But when we tried using the Mobile-Friendly Test tool, these dynamic loading JSON-LD script tags are loading without data:

[image]

What might be the issue?

Comment: Do these tag appear in the page source when you visit the page as mobile user agent?

Comment: @ΣπύροςΓούλας We've tried that one as well. Page source is appearing for the page when we visit the page as mobile user agent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We are using State Transfer API in our application for avoiding multiple service requests and we have only called the LD+JSON method in the server side. Tried calling the same in browser side as well and the issue got fixed.

Thanks, everyone.